# Calling an abstract method in a non-abstract method within an abstract class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, methods, abstract

I have an abstract class in C#:

```
  public void activation()
  {
       activated = true;
       on_Activation();
  }

  protected abstract void on_Activation();
```

Scenario:

Assume I've made a child of the abstract class and made an implementation of the method, `on_Activation()`.

Questions:

- What will happen when I call `Activation()` in the child class?
- Will `on_Activation()` use the implementation of `on_Activation` in the child class?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It's a virtual method (implicitly, because it's abstract) so its "most overridden" version will be called. The fact that the call originates in a method defined on the base class makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. And you have just discovered *polymorphism*. Polymorphism means that you just call a method like `on_Activation` on an object (whether the current object called `this`, or any other object) and you do not need to specify which version of `on_Activation` you mean. It is the actual *type* of the object at runtime that decides which version of `on_Activation` actually gets called.

As Thomas noted, methods which behave this way are called *virtual*. All abstract methods are virtual in C#. So a virtual method is a name, a symbol, that can *polymorphically* refer to different things (different method *bodies*) at runtime.

If you are curious and want to know what kind of magic is involved, you can check the details at [Virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). Essentially every virtual method name like `on_Activation` is translated as an index like `n`, that is the `n`th virtual method of this class. Every non-abstract class provides a table in which all its virtual methods *bodies* are specified. So, a call to `on_Activation` on an object is translated as a call to the `n`th entry in the virtual method table of the class of that object.